# Updating derived values in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Usual sqlalchemy usage:

my_prop = Column("my_prop", Text)

I would like different semantics. Let's say an object has a set of fields (propA, propB, propC). I would like to maintain a database column which is derived from these fields (let's say, propA + propB + propC). I would like the column to be updated whenever any one of these set of fields is updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hybrid properties](http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) provide the functionality you are looking for.  They allow you to write python properties that are usable in queries.

Here's how you might start if you wanted to have a name column and provide access to first and last name properties.

```
@hybrid_property
def first_name(self):
    # get the first name from the name column

@first_name.setter
def first_name(self, value):
    # update the name column with the first name replaced

@first_name.expression
def first_name(cls):
    # return a sql expression that extracts the first name from the name column
    # this is appropriate to be used in queries
```